# Programming katas for scala context and view bounds

Tags: scala

Are there any examples of programming problems (katas) to better understand Scala context and view boundaries and other more esoteric parts of the type system for someone coming from a traditional object orientated background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. Don't have a direct answer, but some hints.

If you are willing to invest, you could take Lightbends "Advanced Scala" course, that covers the type system (including context and view bounds) in detail.

Context bounds are closely related to the concept of type classes. If you google Scala Type Classes, you should find quite a few tutorials, and talks such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1e9tcymPl7w etc.

Also, both are "syntatic sugar" for implicit parameters. So instead of material on context bounds, you could look for material on implicits.

For exercises / katas, check https://www.scala-exercises.org/, e.g. https://www.scala-exercises.org/scala_tutorial/type_classes

For an overview of all the other "esoteric" parts you might be interested in sooner or later, there's quite a comprehensive overview on http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/